# Spring JMS re-registering durable subscription

Tags: ibm-mq, publish-subscribe, websphere-7, spring-jms, subscriptions

I'm working on an application that uses Spring JMS (v3.1.0) to consume some messages from a topic (IBM WebSphere MQ v7) and the monitoring on the MQ show that on each invocation of the listener we refresh/re-register the durable subscription. This is causing an undesired overload on MQ. May worth mention also that the app is running on running on IBM WepSphere v7.

This is our config:

```
<bean id="myMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestResolver"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="myTopic"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myTopicConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
    <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true"/>
    <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="${durableSubscriptionName}"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />

    <!-- Only CACHE_CONSUMER will lead to a fixed registration:
    http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#isRegisteredWithDestination%28%29
    -->
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />

    <!-- clientId already specified on the Topic Connection Factory -->
</bean>

<!-- Lookup the topic -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myTopic" jndi-name="${myTopic.jndiName}" />

<!-- Lookup the topic connection factory -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myTopicConnectionFactory" jndi-name="${myTopicConnectionFactory.jndiName}" />

<!-- Implements javax.jms.MessageListener -->
<bean id="myMessageListener" class="com.sample.jms.MyMessageListener" />

<!-- Get WebSphere work manager --> 
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
   <property name="workManagerName" value="${taskManager.jndiName}" />
</bean>

<!-- 
    Lookup WebSpere transaction manager. More info see: 
    http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-application-server-integration-websphere 
 -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>
```

**EDIT**:
These are the properties we're using:

```
durableSubscriptionName=myMessageListenerContainer
myTopic.jndiName=jms/myTopic
myTopicConnectionFactory.jndiName=jms/myTopicConnectionFactory
taskManager.jndiName=wm/default
```

Any ideas how to solve that?
Thanks! Andre

Comment: How is `<property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="${durableSubscriptionName}"/>` populated?  Could this be a case of generating a different name each time?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's being populated through a properties file and it don't change once the application is running.

Comment: Andre, did you resolve this problem ? If so, pls post an answer.

Comment: We couldn't solve the problem, so we decide to implement the listeners with MDB+Spring. My guess is that WAS is making a pool of the connections and sends to Spring a handler, which will then provide the physical connection. However, this physical connection changes every time because WAS does not know that is the same client. And that's why it doesn't work even if you cache the consumer on the Spring, because your not cache the "real" object, you're caching a WAS handler.

Answer (score 0):

In my own research with Websphere + Spring, I came across this.  Maybe it will help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/795767/945150

Basically Spring is creating lots and lots of connections without using a pool